# How to solve a Cache error in Next.js App?

Tags: css, webpack, caching, next.js, fonts

I'm getting the following error when I try to 'npm run build' I can see it's related the css and fonts but I'm not sure how to debug this issue. App works in development mode.

Error from 'npm run build' below.

Failed to compile.

RealContentHashPlugin
Some kind of unexpected caching problem occurred.
An asset was cached with a reference to another asset (24b9e760) that's not in the compilation anymore.
Either the asset was incorrectly cached, or the referenced asset should also be restored from cache.
Referenced by:

- static/css/55b8cbc3b7204d90.css: .../_next/static/media/24b9e760aff7cc76-s.p.otf) fo...

RealContentHashPlugin
Some kind of unexpected caching problem occurred.
An asset was cached with a reference to another asset (4b68d250) that's not in the compilation anymore.
Either the asset was incorrectly cached, or the referenced asset should also be restored from cache.
Referenced by:

- static/css/55b8cbc3b7204d90.css: .../_next/static/media/4b68d25051f43df4-s.p.ttf) fo...

RealContentHashPlugin
Some kind of unexpected caching problem occurred.
An asset was cached with a reference to another asset (9494b772) that's not in the compilation anymore.
Either the asset was incorrectly cached, or the referenced asset should also be restored from cache.
Referenced by:

- static/css/55b8cbc3b7204d90.css: .../_next/static/media/9494b77224b41738-s.p.ttf) fo...

RealContentHashPlugin
Some kind of unexpected caching problem occurred.
An asset was cached with a reference to another asset (77be99c9) that's not in the compilation anymore.
Either the asset was incorrectly cached, or the referenced asset should also be restored from cache.
Referenced by:

- static/css/55b8cbc3b7204d90.css: .../_next/static/media/77be99c9dd796794-s.p.otf) fo...

RealContentHashPlugin
Some kind of unexpected caching problem occurred.
An asset was cached with a reference to another asset (87eb93ef) that's not in the compilation anymore.
Either the asset was incorrectly cached, or the referenced asset should also be restored from cache.
Referenced by:

- static/css/55b8cbc3b7204d90.css: .../_next/static/media/87eb93ef18013225-s.p.otf) fo...

> Build failed because of webpack errors

Tried to run 'npm run build' and I expected a production build. But Instead I got the errors I mentioned related to css, fonts and cache.

Comment: Ever found a solution for this? I'm running into the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this by deleting the `cache` folder inside `.next` folder. This error is due to some inconsistency with the build genereted